# Separating my Controller and Factory from App.js - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to separate my Controllers and Factories from out of my large **app.js** file. I learned Angular by putting everything into one file, but now I am trying to organize it all by separating my files.

Originally I had something like this (**app.js**).

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  })

  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  })

  .when('/faq', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/faq.html',
    controller: 'FAQController'
  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/unknown'
  });
});

app.factory('FAQMethodService', function() {
  return {
    faqs: [
      {
        question : "Another FAQ",
        answer : "Another FAQ."
      },
      {
        question : "Another FAQ",
        answer : "Another FAQ."
      },
      {
        question : "Another FAQ",
        answer : "Another FAQ."
      },
      {
        question : "Another FAQ",
        answer : "Another FAQ."
      }
    ]
  };
});

app.controller('FAQController', function($scope, FAQMethodService) {
  $scope.faqList = FAQMethodService.faqs;
  $scope.title = "FAQ";
});

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Home";
});
```

For my first step of separation I deleted the section of *FAQController* from **app.js**, and made a new file called **faqController.js** (which I included in my index.html).

```
angular.module('app').controller('FAQController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, FAQMethodService) {
  $scope.faqList = FAQMethodService.faqs;
  $scope.title = "FAQ";
}]);
```

When I open my FAQ page I get the *$scope.title* variable (as I display it), but my *FAQMethodService* information does not show up.

**Question**: How can I get my Factory when my Controller is in another file (and can I separate my Factory to another file too)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When registering things using the array notation, the names and sequence of string arguments must match exactly with the sequence of the constructor function's parameters.

You have a mismatch. You've asked Angular to inject $http into your controller as FAQMethodService

`.controller('FAQController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, FAQMethodService) {`

It should be:

`.controller('FAQController', ['$scope', 'FAQMethodService', function($scope, FAQMethodService) {`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Will separating my Factory (FAQMethodService) be the same thing, but `.factory`, instead of `.controller`?